# Send JSON data from Web Site to Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

data = '[{"yer" : "Besiktas", "lat" : "41.044161", "lng" : "29.001056"},{"yer" : "Eminönü", "lat" : "41.017513", "lng" : "28.970939"},{"yer" : "Zeytinburnu", "lat" : "40.990828", "lng" : "28.895325"}]';
```

The HTML page I wrote above contains a few lines of code and the contents of the json file.

My question is about:
I want to use a web service (API). After opening the html page and reading the data in the json file, I want to send the variable MyData to the Node.js (or it does not matter in any way whatsoever) I am using for the web service. Then I would like to manipulate this data in node.js as well. How should I approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to create a post request to send the data to web server (in your case Node.js as you pointed out).

[Express](https://expressjs.com/) is a good web framework for Node.js to get started with.

Now you also have to accept the data on the server as well.  So you will need to create a [post route within express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your website is going to use a lot of these calls you could use [socket.io](https://socket.io/)
otherwise you can make Express server on Node.JS and send POST request to your server